# Meaning of the term "subcube"

Tags: geometry, terminology

I'm writing a paper and I am dealing with sets such as $\{v\in \{0,1\}^3 : v_1=1, v_2=0\}$, i.e., subsets of an $n$-dimensional Boolean cube where some coordinates are fixed. What is the correct term for such an object? Is "subcube" appropriate, even though these things might form lines or planes?

Comment: Go ahead.  (You might stick in an explanatory comment when you introduce the term, like "Special cases of an $n$-subcube are $n=0,1,2$ when the subsets contain $1$, $2$, and $4$ points, respectively" or something.)

Comment: "Subcube" is fine. Nobody will be confused by 0-, 1-, or 2-dimensional subcube.

Answer (score 0):

For cubes $C\subset{\mathbb R}^n$ a *subcube* is an axis-aligned subset $C'\subset C$ which is still a full $n$-dimensional cube.

I'd rather call  sets of the described type **faces** of the full binary cube $\{0,1\}^n$. Note that the faces of a polyhedron in ${\mathbb R}^n$ may have any dimension between $0$ and $n$.